# How to patch in uwsgi on a flask/socketio that lives inside a class and is starting in a thread

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, uwsgi, flask-socketio

I've written a bot to monitor a gameserver, provide a webinterface and communicate over sockets with clients. All of this works very well so far, running out of the flask development server.

I'd love to get this to work with uwsgi, as flask recommends not using their integrated webserver (even though it seems to work just fine)

I am at a complete loss. Started this thing as a learning project, tried to teach myself things as I went along. Now I have this thing here that doesn't look like anything found in examples, tutorials or documentation, and I really don't even know where to start.

All the docs and tutorials speak of entry points to provide for the uwsgi-server like module:app

But such a structure does not exist for me. it would more be like "global_variable:instance_of_a_class:variable:app"

I've tried to simplify it as much as I could here:

```
imports...

class Webserver(Module):
    app = object
    websocket = object
    login_manager = object

    def get_module_identifier():
        return "module_webserver"

    def run(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = pulled_from_db

        login_manager = LoginManager()
        login_manager.init_app(app)

        self.app = app
        self.websocket = SocketIO(
            app,
            async_mode=pulled_from_db,
            debug=pulled_from_db,
            engineio_logger=pulled_from_db,
            use_reloader=pulled_from_db,
            passthrough_errors=True,
            ping_timeout=15,
            ping_interval=5
        )
        self.login_manager = login_manager

        websocket_instance = Thread(
            target=self.websocket.run,
            args=[self.app],
            kwargs={
                "host": pulled_from_db,
                "port": pulled_from_db
            }
        )
        websocket_instance.start()

        while not self.stopped.wait(self.next_cycle):
            ... do the modules tasks

# modules get instantiated when their file gets imported
loaded_modules_dict[Webserver().get_module_identifier()] = Webserver()
```

This class is loaded on demand and might not always be there at all. How can I get this thing working with uwsgi? Any and all suggestions would be appreciated

I'm using those things inside of other modules, referencing to it via modules.webserver.whatever() type of calls

full code would be here: [link to my projects webserver module](https://code.mhmmm.net/wwevo/chrani-bot-tng/src/branch/master/bot/modules/webserver/__init__.py)

I'm afraid and prepared to have to change the entire structure of the project, but if there's any chance to get it to work as is, that would be grand. Any and all suggestions and tips would be appreciated - I sadly haven't even found the beginning of an idea on how to approach this. My understanding of uwsgi is poor, even after reading hours and hours of docs and examples. The whole concept is alien to me :)

My only idea would be to somehow single out this module, load it on it's own and try to pass that to. No. I have no idea at all. I know it is expected that someone asking a question would provide things they've tried. But I don't even know where to start thinking. I fear that my entire project is simply too much on the self-tought side to be salvageable :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing a couple of things.

A reverse proxy (such as nginx) is a completely independent web server that sits between the clients and your real web server. You do not need to change anything about your application to reverse proxy it, just start nginx configured to forward requests to it, and then have clients talk to nginx instead of your app. That's all it takes.

You also mention that you are using the Flask dev server for your app. That is not a good idea because that web server is slow and not very robust. Some popular choices for web servers are gunicorn and uwsgi, both of which you normally start from the command-line, which is not a model that you have followed, since your web server sits in a background thread of your application. My suggestion is that you use either eventlet or gevent, both of which have production-ready web servers. After you run `pip install eventlet` for example, your `socketio.run()` call will automatically use it, with you needed to make any changes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: after managing to actually do the reverse_proxy thing, i now know that those are totally separate. 
Anyhow, I want to use uwsgi, that's what my question really is about. I do not know what entrypoint to use or how to approach this at all. I am using gevent. That still runs through the flask dev server. until I manage to get uwsgi patched in?
This is not made for humans, that much is clear. How can one check wich server is used? I thought it was flask, but if gevent is loaded you are saying it's not anymore? I will try to clean up my question regarding reverse_proxy, thanks.